# How to disable selector specificity in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on the SCSS file and when I hover on any CSS selector "selector specificity" is showing, which is annoying for me when I have to move the mouse. Is there any setting to disable this feature?

Comment: you can increase the tooltip time so the mouse has to be over it a bit of time

Comment: Yeah, I tried that option but was not satisfied with that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to remove that `Selector Specificity` line.  I looked through open and closed github issues and found nothing.  And there doesn't seem to be any relevant setting.

Here is the original issue where the feature was added: [[CSS] Add specificity to hover](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7299) and there is no mention of a setting to enable/disable.  Same with the actual implementing commit.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find any answer on GitHub or anywhere else. for now, I just set `"editor.hover.enabled": false` to get rid of annoying hover effects that I don't use right now. It's not a proper solution but still useful.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution. In the settings search hover. Then disable "Editor>Hover:Enabled".

Comment: Thanks, I am already using that but that disables the hover function for every file type or function.